# How to determine if user has clicked on missed call?

Tags: android, notifications

It seems like when a phone call is missed, there is a new notification "Missed Call" in the notifications list and there is another entry in call logs. 
Is there a way to get a broadcast when user either clicks on the notification entry or goes to call log and clicks on missed call (which then opens up the call details).
What I am after is that after a call is missed, I want to know when user checked that a call was missed and which number it was from...

Thanks

Comment: I did not get any response, therefore I resorted to be creative. What I have done is set a broadcast receiver when user unlocks the screen and then do whatever I need to do. Currently I think its a fair assumption that when user unlocks the screen, at that point they have seen the missed calls notification hence I presume they are checked or cancelled. I hope some one still provide me the actual answer to my question..I'll wait and see